# Pandas conditionally getting results from a previous row without shift (multiple rows have same value)

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have multiple rows in a time series with the same value and would like to go back 1 step in the time series.  I can't use shift as that is ignorant of the duplicate time values.

I know this won't work but I put it in just to illustrate what i'm after.

```
ot['pastvalue'] = ot(['time'] - 1)['somevalue']
```

Here is a more detailed example direct from code if it's not clear.  Some of these rows have the same value but they contain unique data in the other columns.  Even with a sort the amount of rows with unique or non-unique times is arbitrary.  Therefore, doing a simple DataFrame.shift(x) will not achieve the goal, which is again to simply retrieve a value from  the previous time step.

```
ot['time'].head()
Out[140]:
0    2015010112
1    2015010112
2    2015010111
3    2015010111
4    2015010111
Name: time, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Or sample of your `df`  `5` - `6` rows and desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you start with something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 3, 2], 'b': range(5)})
>>> df
    a   b
0   1   0
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
4   2   4
```

You can drop the duplicate by the `'a'` column (which is the equivalent of your time column), then shift the other column:

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates('a').sort_values(by='a').b.shift(-1)
0     2
2     3
3   NaN
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

This gives you the `b` value at the previous `a` value.

Comment: Very nice!  Why didn't I think of that? Thanks!